# I cannot use the form which I've opened from Timers.Timer event

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am a beginner in C#.
My idea is to create an application which is checking remote web site and show some form if condition is true. So it checks every 10 second, it should works like a notifier.
I start  a timer when start my application.

```
static class Program
{
     [STAThread]
 static void Main()
  {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    TimerEvent timer = new TimerEvent();
    timer.startTimer();
    Application.Run();
 }
}
```

Then I open the form every 10 second.

```
class TimerEvent
{
    public void startTimer()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);


        aTimer.Interval = 10000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

It opens every 10 second new form, but I cannot use it.
I assuming that I missed something about threading.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Solution for me [C# open a new form, and close a form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/936c8ca3-0809-4ddb-890c-426521fe60f1/c-open-a-new-form-and-close-a-form?forum=winforms)

Comment: What does "cannot use it" mean? Did you want more than 1 Form?

Comment: It means I cannot press a button on this form.

Comment: Still not a very detailed description. Does the button react at all? Any errors? And how about my 2nd question?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `System.Timers.Timer` without using the  SynchronizingObject property. That means you are calling Show() from a pool thread, it should not work at all (in Debug mode).

Also you are calling Application.Run() without specifying a MainForm.

The solution dpends on what you actually want to happen (a new Form per 10 seconds gets pretty messy quickly).

Use a normal MainForm and a `Windows.Forms.Timer` to pop up new Forms.

> I assuming that I missed something about threading.

The main thing to know is that the UI is single-threaded by design. Use events, not threads.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I must clarify, my idea is to create an application which is checking remote web site and show some form if condition is true. So it checks every 10 second, it should works like a notifier.

Comment: OK, then don't use threads for the GUI. You may use async for the web connections but you'll have to use `Control.Invoke()` to show the results. Or study the new async/await system.

Comment: As @Henk Holterman said, start a main form from application.run method. And try to do wat u're doing from that main form. Thst will help u achieve your objective.